# Adding a GridViewRowCollection to the asp.net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-controls

i have a record of a gridviewrowcollection. and i'm having issues with adding them to the grid.

```
GridViewRowCollection dr = new GridViewRowCollection(list);
StatisticsGrid.DataSource = dr;
```

doesnt work.

```
StatisticsGrid.Rows
```

does have an add method, what is strange

how can i add a gridviewrowcollection without creating a datatable + binding it to the datasource??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GridView` needs to be bound to a `DataSource` of some type. The GridViewRowCollection is immutable.

Depending on what you want to bind you might find it more fitting to bind to a generic list. This has the benefits over a `DataSet` of being strongly-typed and more naturally fitting to a domain-model:

```
IList<MyClass> data = // Get List<MyClass> of your data
StatisticsGrid.DataSource = data;
```